# How is feature importance calculated for GradientBoostingClassifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-selection

I'm using scikit-learn's gradient-boosted trees classifier, [GradientBoostingClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier.html).  It makes feature importance score available in `feature_importances_`.  How are these feature importances calculated?

I'd like to understand what algorithm scikit-learn is using, to help me understand how to interpret those numbers.  The algorithm isn't listed in the documentation.

Comment: It's documented here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#feature-importance-evaluation

Comment: Thanks, @EdChum!  It turns out that wasn't quite the right link (the link you gave is the documentation for RandomForests and ExtraTrees), but it helped me find the answer for GradientBoostingClassifier.  I wrote an answer that explains.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 13):

This is documented [elsewhere](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#feature-importance) in the scikit-learn documentation.  In particular, here is how it works:

For each tree, we calculate the feature importance of a feature F as the fraction of samples that will traverse a node that splits based on feature F (see [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#random-forest-feature-importance)).   Then, we average those numbers across all trees (as described [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#feature-importance)).

It is not described exactly how scikit-learn estimates the fraction of nodes that will traverse a tree node that splits on feature F.

The interpretation: scores will be in the range [0,1].  Higher scores mean the feature is more important.  This is an array with shape (n_features,) whose values are positive and sum to 1.0